# Laravel skip and delete records from Database

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, record

I'm developing an app which needs to record a list of a users recent video uploads. Importantly it needs to only remember the last two videos associated with the user so I'm trying to find a way to just keep the last two records in a database.

What I've got so far is the below, which creates a new record correctly, however I then want to delete all records that are older than the previous 2, so I've got the below.

The problem is that this seems to delete ALL records even though, by my understanding, the skip should miss out the two most recent records,

```
private function saveVideoToUserProfile($userId, $thumb ...)
{
    RecentVideos::create([
        'user_id'=>$userId,
        'thumbnail'=>$thumb,
        ...
    ]);
    RecentVideos::select('id')->where('user_id', $userId)->orderBy('created_at')->skip(2)->delete();
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`Limit` and `offset` do not work with delete, so you can do something like this:

```
$ids = RecentVideos::select('id')->where('user_id', $userId)->orderByDesc('created_at')->skip(2)->take(10000)->pluck('id');
RecentVideos::whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, `skip()` does not skip the *x* number of recent records, but rather the *x* number of records from the beginning of the result set. So in order to get your desired result, you need to sort the data in the correct order. `orderBy()` defaults to ordering ascending, but it accepts a second direction argument. Try `orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')`. (See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#ordering) on `orderBy()`.)

This is how I would recommend writing the query.

```php
RecentVideos::where('user_id', $userId)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->skip(2)->delete();
```